# svg raphael contextMenu right click T.T sos

Tags: svg, contextmenu, raphael, right-click

Does Raphael support having right click menu?? 
I'm looking into how to best visualise a UML like diagram, but also 
have the ability for the user to hover over one fo the items and say 
"create relationship" or "create new node" (so a right click menu 
would be good).  I'm trying to understand if Raphael would help me out.

my question Similar to the above.

i hava javascript support right click menu about svg demo.

svgmenu.js file:

```
var CurveControl = null;
var SvgMainMapDoc = null;
function winLoad(){
     CurveControl = document.getElementById('NavigateControl');
     if(CurveControl==null)
         return;
     SvgMainMapDoc = CurveControl.getSVGDocument();
     faireMenus("menu1");
}

function faireMenus(udefMenuID){//== udefMenuID:svg预定义的菜单编码 
    var udef_menu = udefMenuID;
    var mydoc = SvgMainMapDoc;
    var contextMenu = CurveControl.window.contextMenu;
    var menuXml = CurveControl.window.printNode(mydoc.getElementById(udef_menu));
    //alert(menuXml);
    CurveControl.window.Titi = Titi;
    CurveControl.window.printit = printit;
    CurveControl.window.colorit = colorit;
    CurveControl.window.showmsg = showmsg;
    changeMenus(menuXml);
}
function changeMenus(menuXml){//== xml格式的菜单字符串
    var contextMenu = CurveControl.window.contextMenu;
    var newMenuRoot = CurveControl.window.parseXML(menuXml, contextMenu);
    contextMenu.replaceChild(newMenuRoot, contextMenu.firstChild);
}
function Titi()
{
    var msg = "test";
    alert(msg);
}
function printit(){
    if (confirm('确定打印吗？')){ 
      try {
        if(parent) parent.print();
      } 
      catch(e){}
    }
}
function colorit(clr){ //背景色函数
    var myob = SvgMainMapDoc.getElementById("rect_back");
    if(myob) myob.setAttribute("fill", clr);
}
function showmsg(msg){ 
    alert(msg);
}
```

svgmenu.svg file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>     
<svg id="cont" viewBox="0 0 450 320" width="450" height="320" 
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
 xml:space="preserve" preserveAspectRatio="none">   

<defs>       
<menu id='menu1'>
    <header>Menu utilisateur</header>
    <item action="CopySVG" id="CopySVG">复制图形</item>
    <separator/>
    <menu>
       <header>背景颜色</header>
        <item onactivate="colorit('white')">白色</item>
        <item onactivate="colorit('black')">黑色</item>
        <item onactivate="colorit('#D0D063')">黄色</item>
        <item onactivate="colorit('green')">绿色</item>
        <separator/>
        <item onactivate="colorit('#008083')">默认</item>     
    </menu>
    <separator/>
    <item action="Pause" id="Pause">暂停</item>
    <separator/>
    <item id='Menu1.2' onactivate='printit(this)'>打印</item>
    <separator/>
    <item id='Menu1.1' onactivate='Titi()'>操作说明</item>
    </menu> 
    <menu id='menu2'>
        <item id='Menu1.2' onactivate="showmsg('控件ID')">控件ID</item>
</menu> 
</defs>
<g id="elements"> 
<rect id="rect_back" class="Gas" x="0" y="0" width ="450" height="320" fill="#ffff33">
</rect> 
<rect id="gas_1" class="Gas" x="0" y="0" width ="145" height="145" fill="#00ff33"     onmouseover="faireMenus('menu2')" onmouseout="faireMenus('menu1')">
</rect> 
</g> 
</svg>
```

svgmenu.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script language="JavaScript" src="svgmenu.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="winLoad()">
<embed id="NavigateControl" width="100%" height="100%" src="svgmenu.svg"     type="image/svg+xml" >
</body>
</html>
```

but....
i want to use RaphaelJs to create svg gragh.

some raphael(reference:http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html) code:

```
var c = R.circle(100, 100, 50).attr({
    fill: "hsb(.8, 1, 1)",
    stroke: "none",
    opacity: .5
});
var start = function () {
    // storing original coordinates
    this.ox = this.attr("cx");
    this.oy = this.attr("cy");
    this.attr({opacity: 1});
},
move = function (dx, dy) {
    // move will be called with dx and dy
    this.attr({cx: this.ox + dx, cy: this.oy + dy});
},
up = function () {
    // restoring state
    this.attr({opacity: .5});
};
c.drag(move, start, up);
```

now...
**i hava raphaelJs move function. 
i hava javascript right menu Redefinition function. 
i want Combining these two functions. 
how can i do?** 
if you hava any idea. leave your answer. Thank you very much.
by the way:
if the source code has some wrong also can be pointed out that

Answer (score 2):

```
$(c.node).bind("contextmenu", function(){
    alert(0);
});
```

Please try the code above, $ == jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you could add a context menu to an svg element using DOJO. It will appear on right click.

```
var contextMenu = new dijit.Menu();

contextMenu.addChild(
    new dijit.MenuItem( {
        label:"Menu item", 
        onClick:function(e){ log.debug("Clicked"); } 
}));

contextMenu.bindDomNode(raphaelElement[0] );
```

RaphaelElement is a your raphael element, like a circle or ellipse.